# ChartJS set styling on the last point only

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart where all the visual points are disabled, I have disabled them by doing this:

```
const options = {
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0,
      },
    }
```

My issue is that I actually want to have the point enabled only for the very last point, please see this image: http://prntscr.com/1tq0zql

I have found a way to target that last line by using segments:

```
const data = {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: tgpDatasets,
        borderColor: "rgba(103,120,137,1)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        segment: {
          borderColor: ({ p0DataIndex, p1DataIndex }) => p0DataIndex === 8 && p1DataIndex === 9 && "red",
        },
      },
    ],
  };
```

The above code will make the last line of the chart red, please see this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/1tq155f

My question is how to enable a point for that very last point of the chart and set its porperties, when the radius is controlled from the `options` object and not from the `dataset` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scriptable options for this like so:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink',
        backgroundColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange',
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: (ctx) => (ctx.chart.data.datasets[ctx.datasetIndex].data.length - 1 === ctx.index ? 10 : 0)
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that I can use a function there too! Is that function available for all sorts of options, in datasets, in options, like everywhere?

Comment: Depends on the option, if you go to the documentation and it says its scriptable yeah those kind of functions are supported else not